# Does GStreamer internally use the ffmpeg code?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am looking for some implementations in ffmpeg adn gstreamers, for muxers. I downloaded the source code for ffmpeg and gstreamer. Gstreamer internally has ffmpeg files. I have not built the workspace for gstreamer. So could anyone clarify as to what code of ffmpeg is sitting inside the GStreamer

Answer (score 1):

The whole of libav (and before ffmpeg) is wrapped by "gst-libav" (previously "gst-ffmpeg"). When you launch a pipeline with a playbin, it's this implementation that will get used, not your system-wide ffmpeg.